# Why do the fonts used by achemso look different between computers?

Tags: fonts, achemso

I have the same latex file on two Macs: one running 10.7 (Lion) and one 10.9 (Mavericks). Both Macs have the same latest versions of `achemso`, TeXShop etc. All the packages have been updated with TeX Live Utility so I assume that in terms of LaTeX packages, the two computers should give the same manuscript. In fact no. The TeX file compiled on OS 10.9 gives a PDF file that seems to be using Computer Modern fonts whereas on 10.7 the fonts look different.
eg:

- Title of the article: looks like Arial on Mac OS 10.7 and Arial Rounded on 10.9,
- Text: looks like Times New Roman on 10.7 but Garamond on 10.9.

Does anyone know what's happening? How can I have the same fonts on 10.9 as on 10.7? I assume that what I get on 10.7 with achemso is what I should be getting because I get the same results as on 10.7 when I compiled my tex file on a Linux machine.
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx.  Can you make a minimal document that also shows the different outputs and post images of them? (You can easily capture a screen shot by using Command-Option-4 and then selecting a portion.)  You don't have enough reputation to embed the images at the moment, so remove the `!` from the markup and then a higher rep user can put it back in.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the same version of `achemso` on the two systems then you should get the same fonts: add `\listfiles` to your input and look over the logs to find out if this is the case.

The reason for a font change between versions is that when I first wrote the class the ACS were using Times for their journals, so it seemed sensible to use `mathptmx` in the class file. However, since then the ACS have changed to a commercial alternative font, and at the same time there are various symbols that work poorly with `mathptmx`. As such, the best 'fix' seems to be to avoid doing any font setting at all. Thus more recent versions of `achemso` will use Computer Modern unless you deliberately set the font yourself.